# How do I return a list of the 3 lowest values in another list

Tags: python, min, built-in

How do I return a list of the 3 lowest values in another list.  For example I want to get the 3 lowest values of this list:

```
in_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
input: function(in_list, 3)
output: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: There can be many ways.  What approach did you come up with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`heapq.nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> in_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> nsmallest(3, in_list)
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: There are interesting notes about `heapq.nsmallest` in comment in CPython source https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/heapq.py#L395

Answer (score 9):

If you could sort,you can get frst 3 elements as below:

```
 alist=[6, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1]
 sorted(alist)[:3]
```

Output:

```
 [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

even simpler without modules imported:

```
l =[3,8,9,10,2,4,1]
l1 = sorted(l)[:3]
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If your lists are long, the most efficient way of doing this is via [`numpy.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
>>> def lowest(a, n): return numpy.partition(a, n-1)[:n]
>>> in_list = [6, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1]
>>> lowest(in_list, 3)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

This executes in O(N) time, unlike a full sort which would operate in O(NlogN) time. The time savings come from not performing a full sort, but only the minimal amount needed to ensure that the `n` lowest elements are first. Hence the output is not necessarily sorted.

If you need them to be sorted, you can do that afterwards (`numpy.sort(lowest(in_list,3)) => array([1,2,3])`). For a large array this will still be faster than sorting the whole thing first.

Edit: Here is a comparison of the speed of `numpy.partition`, `heapq.nsmallest` and `sorted`:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.permutation(np.arange(1000000))
>>> timeit numpy.partition(a, 2)[:3]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.32 ms per loop
>>> timeit heapq.nsmallest(3,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 220 ms per loop
>>> timeit sorted(a)[:3]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.18 s per loop
```

So `numpy.partition` is 66 times faster than `heapq.nsmallest` for an array with a million elements, and it is 355 times faster than `sorted`. This doesn't mean that you should never use `heapq.nsmallest` (which is very flexible), but it demonstrates how important it is to avoid plain lists when speed is important.

Comment: This does transform the original list into a `np.array()` object.

Comment: Note that `heapq.nsmallest()` does the same thing, plus the sort, in roughly the same order of complexity; it takes O(NlogK) time, where K is the number of elements to be returned. Both `numpy.partition()` and `heapq` are backed by C code. The fact that `heapq` then returns a Python list could be seen as an advantage over `numpy.partition()`.

Comment: Yes. But then, if your lists are long you want to be using arrays instead of lists anyway, since they are so much faster and use much less memory. If you want the output to be a plain list, just do `list(lowest(in_list,3))`.

Comment: What about an iterable? The `heapq.nsmallest()` function doesn't require all values to be in memory in a list. You can process a large file efficiently finding the longest 3 lines with `heapq.nlargest(3, fileobj, key=len)`, and you never need more memory than 4 lines plus a read-ahead buffer.

Comment: Yes, iterables are flexible and can save a lot of memory. But they aren't very fast, since the iteration happens in python. I have updated my answer with a small benchmark to illustrate my point.

Comment: *since the iteration happens in python*: that happens on how the iterator is used. For a file it doesn't really matter, as I/O is the bottleneck there anyway.

Comment: How can one use an iterable in such a way that the iteration does not incur python overhead? I did not think that was possible. About I/O being the overhead: I created a text file with a million lines, and performed 4 tests on it: 1. Read the file in C, discarding the input: 7 ms; 2. Read the file in python using `file.read()`, discarding the output: 35 ms; 3: Iterate over lines in python, discarding the output: 49 ms; 4. `heapq.nlargest(3, file, key=len)`: 265 ms. So clearly I/O is not the bottleneck - python is.

Comment: How did you measure the time required? Other processes, swapping and disk flushes can have *huge* impact on time measured, so unless you repeat the experiment in a controlled manner you won't be measuring anything accurately. There are several C-backed functions that'll loop over an iterable in C code, not Python code. It all depends.

Comment: For python I used `timeit`. For C, I took a shortcut and did `time for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do cat foo.txt >/dev/null ; done` in the shell, and divided the result by 100. This will also include the overhead from starting `cat` several time, so the result will be an upper bound on the time C takes. Which is still much faster than python. But these tests took me just 2 minutes or so to perform, so you can easily verify it yourself.

I would be grateful for an example of code that uses an iterable from C without incurring python overhead.

Comment: `map()` and `filter` and any of the `itertools` methods would iterate over an iterable in C code, for example. Doing a file read entirely in C and ignoring everything else Python does when reading a file (in Python 3, decode to `str()`, and in either 2 or 3, translate native line endings to `\n`, build `str()` objects for lines all play too, quite apart from the iteration itself).

Comment: Most of all, I wanted to add side notes to your approach in the answer; not go into a detailed discussion over what would or would not be faster. There are additional things to consider when picking `numpy.partition` over `heapq.nsmallest`, was all I wanted to convey.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is the reasonable approach. If you care about asymptotic complexity though, you'd want to do this in time O(n) and space O(1).

```
def k_min(values, k):
    return sorted(values)[:k]
```

Calling to `sorted()` can give you time only O(n*log n) and space O(n), so to achieve O(n) time and O(1) space, different approach is needed.

For that, you'd iterate through the list (that's where O(n) comes from) and keep track of the `k` minimal elements seen so far, which can be done in constant time (since `k` is here a constant).

For keeping track of the minimal elements, you can use a heap (module `heapq`), or a list. In case of list, time is O(n*k) and in case of heap time is O(n*log k). In any case, because `k` is for you a constant, this whole thing will end up linear in `n` in total.

Using a list (which is bit simpler to use than the heap, though of course bad if k is large), it may look like this

```
def k_min(values, k):
    minima = []  # len(minima) <= k + 1
    for v in values:
        minima.append(v)
        if len(minima) > k:
            minima.remove(max(minima))  # O(k) == O(1)
    return minima
```