# How do I return the 3 lowest numbers in a list without sorting?

Tags: python

I need to get the 3 lowest numbers in a list but need to maintain the order that they are positioned in the list so sorting doesn't work.

here is the list `minimums`

```
[7.67, 8.06, 8.01, 8.52, 8.46, 1.40]
```

so my expected outcome would be

```
[7.67, 8.01, 1.40]
```

Comment: Please add a sample input, and the corresponding expected output

Comment: "but need to maintain the order that they are positioned in the list so sorting doesn't work." why does that mean sorting doesn't work? Just create another list using `sorted_minimums = sorted(minimums)` and `minimums` won't be affected

Comment: I voted close on your question, as the desired output and input are unclear. Be **clear**,  I've this input and I need this output.

Comment: Just updated the desired input and output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return a list of the 3 lowest values in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117834/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-the-3-lowest-values-in-another-list) check user7610's answer

Comment: @Errol `nsmallest` returns the items in the sorted order, not in the original order.

Comment: @Errol the problem you linked does not include **keeping the original order** of the 3 lowest values.

Comment: @DYZ, user7610's answer returns the items in same order as the original list

Comment: @Blotosmetek user7610's answer is almost same as your answer.

Comment: @Errol thanks for the link, unfortunately I've tried all the answers in that question but all either returned errors or returned a sorted list.

Comment: @Errol Yes, you are right.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually user7610's solution is likely better than mine in efficiency terms.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to avoid sorting not because of the sorting overhead, but because you want to preserve the order of the original elements.

You can first sort by the value (but record the position), then choose the three smallest items, and then sort them by the original positions:

```
orig = [7.67, 8.06, 8.01, 8.52, 8.46, 1.40]
l1 = sorted(enumerate(orig), key=lambda x: x[1])[:3]
[x for _,x in sorted(l1)]
#[7.67, 8.01, 1.4]
```

Comment: I need to make lamda part of my go to... I still think procedural and it's not nearly as clean or efficient.  Nice !

Comment: @DYZ you are sorting a list when it's not needed. If the list has billions of elements, sorting is not a way to resolve this problem.

Comment: @politinsa We do not know if sorting is a performance problem.

Comment: @DYZ for a generic problem I prefer to offer a less expensive solution.

Comment: @politinsa Except that your solution does not work.

Comment: Do I need to install a package to use lamda? I am getting an error: unresolved reference 'lamda'

Comment: No, you do not. lambda is a part of the core Python. Check your syntax.

Comment: @DYZ he now have the 3 smallest number as well as their indexes. He can now find out how to sort zip(indexes, minimums) by index.

Answer (score 0):

Everything **including some sorting** algorithm have a complexity of **at least O(n*log(n))**.
Finding the minimum is a **O(n) operation**.

```py
VALUE = max(a) + 1

idx_min0 = a.index(min(a))
min0 = a[idx_min0]
a[idx_min0] = VALUE

idx_min1 = a.index(min(a))
min1 = a[idx_min1]
a[idx_min1] = VALUE

idx_min2 = a.index(min(a))
min2 = a[idx_min2]

a[idx_min0] = min0
a[idx_min1] = min1
a[idx_min2] = min2
```

Comment: Why do you assume the three smallest numbers are all smaller than 9999?

Comment: @Błotosmętek better?

Comment: This code does not compute the three smallest elements arranged in the same order as in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but i can help with the logic

Create 3 variables (or an array) to hold the 3 lowest numbers.
Initialize all 3 to max_number.
Position 0 will hold the lowest number.

Create 3 variables to hold the position (if that is required)

Start scanning from first number to last number - we will call this 'current'

```
If current < Var(2)
  copy current to var(2)
  If current < var(1)
    copy var(1) to var(2)
    copy current to var(1)
    If current < var(0)
      copy var(0) to var(1)
      copy current to var(0)
```

And keep the position likewise in the other array